# If $\int_M \omega=0\Rightarrow \omega=d\varphi$, then $H^n_c(M)\simeq\mathbb{R}$? ($M$ is a connected orientable manifold)

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

I'm reading a book in wich the author uses this argumet the whole time. For example, he assumes that $\int_\mathbb{R}\omega=0$ then $\omega =df$ and then he concludes that that $H^n_c(\mathbb{R})\simeq \mathbb{R}$. Why?

Comment: What are you actually asking about? Whether $\Bbb R$ has the first property? Why it has $H^1_c(\Bbb R) = \Bbb R$?

Comment: @MikeMiller the fact I said about $\mathbb{R}$ is just an example of what the author is doing. I my question is if: $\int_M\omega=0$ implies that $\omega$ is exact, then $H^n_c(M)\simeq\mathbb{R}$ ($\omega$ with compact support)? And, if yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) If $\omega =fdx$, then define $g(t):=\int_{-\infty}^t\omega$
Then $ g'(t)=f(t)$ so that $dg=\omega$

(2) $H^1_c({\bf R})={\bf R}$ : If $\omega$ is $1$-form on compact
support on ${\bf R}$, then $d\omega =0$ And let $\int_{\bf R}\omega
=C$

If $\omega'$ is another form of compact support with $\int_{\bf R} \omega'=C$, then $$  \int_{\bf R} \omega -\omega'= 0$$ Hence **by** $(1)$ **we have** $$ \omega -\omega'=df $$

Since $\omega,\ \omega'$ have compact supports, so do $df$ That is $[\omega]=[\omega']$

To complete the proof, we define $$ \int : H^1_c({\bf R})\rightarrow {\bf R},\  [\omega]\mapsto \int_{\bf R} \omega $$

This is welldefined since $\int_{\bf R} \omega +df=\int_{\bf R} \omega$ And if $\alpha $ is bump $1$-form, i.e., $\int \alpha =1$, compact support is a connected component and $\alpha =gdx \Rightarrow g$ has positive in interior of support, then $\int_{\bf R} C\alpha =C$ Hence it is onto.

Comment: The author did the following: He proves that if $\int_\mathbb{R}\omega=0$ ($\omega$ with compact support), then $\omega= d(f-c)$, where $f-c$ has compact support. I understood that, but how does that prove the assertion?

Comment: $\int : H^1_c({\bf R}) \rightarrow {\bf R},\ \omega \mapsto \int \omega$ Note that this is well defined since all forms in same class have same values. And this is onto : If we have bump $1$-form $\int \alpha =1$, then $\int C\alpha=C$ for any $C$.

Comment: But where's the author using this in my comment?

Comment: I add more explanation

Comment: I see, thank you. But I've already understood your proof of the fact. But yet I don't understand what the author did (as in my comment).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the map $ u : H^n_c(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined setting
$$u: \  [ \omega ] \mapsto  \int_{M} \omega  \ .$$
This is well defined because of Stokes theorem, and is injective because of your assumption. So (under your assumption) either $H^n_c(M)=0$ or $\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand $H^n_c(M)\not=0$ since $u$ is non-zero (working in local coordinates, you can always find a form with compact support and non-zero integral).

Comment: My problem was in the understanding of the author's proof of your claim in parentesis. He first proved the theorem for the case $M=\mathbb{R}$, as in my enunciation. But for that he proved that $\int_\mathbb{R}\omega=0\Rightarrow \omega=d\varphi$ ($\omega$ and $\varphi$ both with compact support) and finishes this part's proof. But how does that really prove the assertion?

Comment: ok, I understand... Next time try to state your question more clearly!

Comment: Yes, I saw my fault here. Sorry. And, answering my own question, we now that $\int \omega-\omega'=0$ if $\omega$ and $\omega'$ are both closed (by stokes), this way, that implication in my question means that $\omega-\omega'$ is exact, so $dim H_c^n\leq 1$.